# Create Hotspot on orangePi and use another usb wifi for internet access

Tags: networking, hot-spot

[image: enter]

can we build and design like this image?
board is orangePi

Comment: is that board a motherboard? have you installed Ubuntu with this motherboard assembled PC? what is your ubuntu version?

Comment: i think it is possible..but practical checking will only give the proper result.. YES or NO..1st step is orangePi's wifi card.. if it supports wifi-Hotspot.. then 2nd step is to connect to this hotspot via TP-Link TL-WN722N